# SQL Query - Count number of consecutive rows with value above X

Tags: sql

I'm stuck on a query and hoping for some guidance.  We want to produce a report that counts how many consecutive dates (looking backwards from a user supplied date) for a product.  Data set is like below:

```
Product, InventoryDate, InventoryQuantity
A, 3/1/2021, 123
B, 3/1/2021, 98
C, 3/1/2021, 101
A, 2/22/2021, 115
B, 2/22/2021, 99
C, 2/22/2021, 105
A, 2/15/2021, 150
B, 2/15/2021, 105
C, 2/15/2021, 50
```

So we'd like to pull a report that says below for supplied date of 3/2/2021:

```
Product, CurrentInventory, PreviousWeeksCountAbove100
A,123,2
B,98,0
C,101,1
```

As much as I'm struggling to write the query, I don't even know what to call this because I need count of consecutive values over a specific threshold.  I can count values above the threshold, but not sure how add the "weeks in a row" logic.

Comment: You can use window functions to do this. What's the specific database?

Comment: What DBMS are you asking this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions.  Assign a group based on the number of rows with a value below X counting from the end.  Then filter and aggregate:

```
select product,
       sum(case when grp = 0 and val > 100 then 1 else 0 end) as consecutive_weeks
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when val <= 100 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by product order by inventorydate desc) as grp
      from t
      where inventorydate <= ?
     ) t
group by product;
```